# Is there a shorter, more natural syntax for exporting binding functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can I directly bind and export a function declaration at the same time?

For example:

✘ Desirable or acceptable but invalid:

```
   export function f() { }.bind({})
//                        ^
   export (function f() { }).bind({})
// ^^^^^^
// Error: "Declaration or statement expected. ts(1128)"
```

✔ Valid but not concise and with a slight awkwardness:

```
export let f = function () { }.bind({})
```

Thanks for answering!

---

#### Update:

In the end, I realized that the following approach was already very satisfactory:

```
export function f() { }
f = f.bind({})
```

Sorry for posting a question that lacks a description of context (or intent)!

Comment: `export default () => ({ }).bind({});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The call to `.bind` will always be a function call expression and not a declaration. The only way to export an expression is to have it as the default export:

```
  export default function() { }.bind({});
```

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want to create and export a singleton?

Then why mess around with `this` and how to `bind` the methods to that object, instead of simply using a closure?

```
const state = {};

export function f() { console.log(state); }
```